# How to integrate Google contacts and calendar in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, calendar, contacts, google-calendar

So I've added my Google account to the online-accounts in the system settings, but unfortunately Gnome programs like Gnome Contacts and California Calendar can't access any information from it. I read online that with the newer Ubuntu systems Gnome programs don't integrate with the configured online accounts, so I'm wondering what's the point of adding them if users have to import and export data manually. I've already tried a lot of solutions I found online regarding this issue, but none of them solved anything (most of the solutions were written for older systems and didn't work for Ubuntu 15.10). So I'm basically wondering if anyone has a solution for syncing Google contacts and calendar with Gnome contacts and California Calendar.

Info about my system: Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit.

Comment: They works fine on 15.10. Google contacts and california both uses evolution-data-server backend. First install `evolution`. Then configure online accounts.  Contacts and calendar should appear in evolution. Then you can use online address-book for gnome contacts.

Comment: Alternatively you can try [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/)

Comment: @Khurshid Alam Thanks, the calendar now works with Evolution. However contacts won't synchronize, I keep getting the error message 'requested resource was not found: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps'.

Comment: See instruction details here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-google-contacts-with-evolution-addressbooks

Answer (score 0):

Many GTK+ apps use evolution-data-server as their backend for calendaring and address books. [Adding your calendars and address books in Evolution](https://www.slightfuture.com/technote/gnome-caldav) will make they appear as data sources in Maya, GNOME Calendar, California, GNOME Contacts, Dash, GNOME To Do, and a bunch of other programs.